# fire ValueChangeEvent from SelectionChangeHandler

Tags: gwt

I have  4 DateBox and they are like :

```
    date1.addValueChangeHandler(new CustomValueChangeHandler());
    date2.addValueChangeHandler(new CustomValueChangeHandler());
    date3.addValueChangeHandler(new CustomValueChangeHandler());
    date4.addValueChangeHandler(new CustomValueChangeHandler());

private class CustomValueChangeHandler implements ValueChangeHandler {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)
    {
```

Now i have a celltable with single selection , and its selectionChange is like :

```
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new Handler() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event)
        {
            Person person = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();

            date1.setValue(person.getStartDate());
            date2.setValue(person.getEndDate());
            date3.setValue(person.getStartTime());
            date4.setValue(person.getEndTime());
        }
    });
```

selection change event is setting date values its ok, but problem is date1,date2,date3,date4 has ValueChangeHandler and they are not triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setValue()` method doesn't fire change event. You can force firing the event with second parameter. Use

```
date1.setValue(person.getStartDate(), true);
```